# Disable Editor Template Date.cshtml on specific view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, editortemplates

My **Model**

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date in the format MM/dd/yyyy")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "From Date")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
```

My **View**

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromDate)
```

My **Date.cshtml** (Editor Templates)

```
@Html.TextBox("", string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now),
 new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
```

**My requirement is show database value on this particular view but every time it shows me current date. How to do this Please help me.**

Comment: WHy are you converting the Date to String and parsing and coverting it back to date again?

Comment: I updated my Date.cshtml but having same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Model` instead of `DateTime.Now`

```
@Html.TextBox("", string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model),
new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
```

Comment: Great it works fine but In all other view shows default 01/01/0001 but i want there current date

Comment: In all other views you'll have to set the property of the model to `DateTime.Now`

Comment: Will you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got alternative solution for this situation

```
   @if (@Model.FromDate != null)
    {
        var frmDate = Model.FromDate;
        @Html.EditorFor(model => frmDate)
    }
```

Thanks For Help.